# What is this drop down history suggestion in an input field for HTML?

Tags: html

For an input field, there's typically a list of recommendations I see in text fields. What are they called? I read there's something called "autocomplete" but I think that's different.

This is the html code:

```
  <input type="text" name="fname">
```

This disappears if I remove the "name=..."

[image: Dropdown]

Comment: That’s your browser providing autocomplete from history

Answer (score 1):

Autocomplete is a browser feature that remembers common input field attributes like "name" or "email" and suggests previously entered values when it encounters similar fields on other websites. When you remove the attribute that identifies an input field as a specific type (e.g., "name"), the browser can't recognize it as such and won't display any previously entered values. Using consistent attribute names helps the browser accurately suggest and autofill the appropriate information. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually called *autocomplete*.

> Autocomplete allows the browser to predict the value. When a user starts to type in a field, the browser should display options to fill in the field, based on earlier typed values.

You can read more [by clicking on this link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp).

Its value can be `on` or `off`.

***Example:***

```
<input type="text" name="fname" autocomplete="on">
```

***Or***

```
<input type="text" name="fname" autocomplete="off">
```

When `autocomplete="off"`, it will not show the suggestions. But if the `autocomplete="on"`, it will show the suggestions based on what you've typed in the past.

And why it's disappearing when you remove the `name="fname`, I don't know either.

If anyone knows, please explain to me also.

Comment: It's disappearing, because the browser stores the history by using the "name" as key. It only shows those earlier entries that match the key.